# Vim: copy/delete line from the first none blank character to the last none blank character

Tags: vim, vi

Most time when I copy or delete some code in Vim use `yy` or `dd`, I also got the indent spaces. Is there a quick command that I can yank a line without leading or trailing spaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a wizard, but:

```
^v$gey
```

works for me.  You can always make an alias.

*EDIT*: here's a better one that doesn't rely on visual mode.

```
^yg_
```

Answer (score 6):

There's another way to solve your implied problem. After you yank line(s) into the buffer, you can then *paste* them using the appropriate indent using `]p` or `]P`. These paste commands automatically adjust the indent of the pasted line(s) to match the indent of the line where the cursor is.